# Segmentation fault. Where am I wrong? C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I need to realize dynamic matrix in C.

I have this code in main:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int rows, cols;

  scanf("%d", &rows);
  scanf("%d", &cols);

  int** A = create_matrix(rows, cols);
  fill_matrix(A, rows, cols);

  add_row(A, &rows, cols);
  print_matrix(A, rows, cols);
  free_matrix(A, rows);
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I allocate matrix, then fill it by:

```
4 3
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
```

and I want to add new row [1, 1, 1], then print, then free. Here are functions

```c
void add_row(int **matrix, int *rows_amount, int cols_amount)
{
  printf("started\n");

  (*rows_amount)++;
  matrix = (int**)realloc(matrix, (*rows_amount) * sizeof(int*));
  matrix[*rows_amount - 1] = (int*)malloc(cols_amount * sizeof(int));

  for (int j = 0; j < cols_amount; j++)
    matrix[*rows_amount - 1][j] = 1;

  printf("ended\n");
  return;
}

int **create_matrix(int rows_amount, int cols_amount) 
{
    int **matrix = (int**)malloc(rows_amount * sizeof(int*));
    for(int i = 0; i < rows_amount; i++) 
        matrix[i] = (int*)malloc(cols_amount * sizeof(int));
    return matrix;
}

void fill_matrix(int **matrix, int rows_amount, int cols_amount) 
{
  for(int i = 0; i < rows_amount; i++)  
        for(int j = 0; j < cols_amount; j++)
            scanf("%d", matrix[i] + j);
}

void free_matrix(int **matrix, int rows_amount) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < rows_amount; i++)  
        free(matrix[i]);
    free(matrix);
}

void print_matrix(int **matrix, int rows_amount, int cols_amount) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < rows_amount; i++)
  {
        for(int j = 0; j < cols_amount; j++)  
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
  }
}
```

When I use valgrind to find the line causes the SEGFAULT, I get this:

```
stepan@WIN-KBCGJ2G97TU:/mnt/d/Desktop/study/sem3/c_prog/lab_09$ valgrind ./app.out < 1.txt 
==2715== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2715== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2715== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2715== Command: ./app.out // I add < d.txt which contains test
==2715==
==2715== error calling PR_SET_PTRACER, vgdb might block
started // between this and next lines no errors! this is in add_row
ended
==2715== Invalid read of size 8
==2715==    at 0x1089F9: print_matrix (matrix.c:33)
==2715==    by 0x109048: main (main.c:19)
==2715==  Address 0x522e080 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 32 free'd
==2715==    at 0x4C31D2F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)      
==2715==    by 0x108DC5: add_row (matrix.c:102)
==2715==    by 0x109034: main (main.c:17)
==2715==  Block was alloc'd at
==2715==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)       
==2715==    by 0x1088A9: create_matrix (matrix.c:8)
==2715==    by 0x109006: main (main.c:11)
==2715==
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4 // on the next line must have been 1 1 1
==2715== Invalid read of size 4
==2715==    at 0x108A09: print_matrix (matrix.c:33)
==2715==    by 0x109048: main (main.c:19)
==2715==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==2715==
==2715==
==2715== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==2715==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==2715==    at 0x108A09: print_matrix (matrix.c:33)
==2715==    by 0x109048: main (main.c:19)
==2715==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==2715==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==2715==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==2715==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==2715==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==2715== 
==2715== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2715==     in use at exit: 100 bytes in 6 blocks
==2715==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 3 frees, 8,324 bytes allocated
==2715==
==2715== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2715==    definitely lost: 40 bytes in 1 blocks
==2715==    indirectly lost: 60 bytes in 5 blocks
==2715==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2715==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2715==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2715== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==2715==
==2715== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2715== ERROR SUMMARY: 14 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So, it seems that some things happen in add_row:

```
matrix = (int**)realloc(matrix, (*rows_amount) * sizeof(int*));
matrix[*rows_amount - 1] = (int*)malloc(cols_amount * sizeof(int));
```

It is true 99.9% because without adding row, just create, fill and free there is no memory errors.

And also I don't understand why `Invalid read of size 8` before all lines printed (`matrix.c:33` is `printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);`), and then he tries to read 4 bytes ¯_(ツ)_/¯.

What is wrong?

UPDATE.

I added return matrix; And in main A = add_row...
And it works! Thanks all you guys for C Memory lesson :)

Comment: `matrix = (int**)realloc(matrix, (*rows_amount) * sizeof(int*));`. That modifies a **local** copy of the `matrix` pointer. That is, the caller of the function will not see the results of this `realloc` as it will still have the old value of `matrix`.

Comment: Wait, matrix contains pointer to some place in memory, then I use realloc by this pointer. No?

Comment: Yes, matrix does point to some place in memory. That's not the issue. The issue is that the `matrix` variable in the function is not the same `matrix` variable as in the caller. The *value* is the same but the variable is not. This is because in C all args are passed by value.

Comment: `matrix` is an address value passed into the function from outside, but when you `realloc()` the memory, this *sometimes* will just extend memory in place, but almost never. In practice it allocates a new chunk somewhere else - with a new address! - and copies the old memory to the new, then frees the old pointer.  After this function runs, the *caller* still has the old pointer before realloc. You'll have to either pass the address of the matrix as `int ***` or just always return the new pointer.

Comment: Do you mean this: https://pastebin.com/tWZKAee3

Comment: `void add_row(int **matrix` changes the *copy of the pointer* `matrix` which has its very own, and very different address from the `matrix` in the caller. Since you do not return `matrix` and assign the new address of the pointer to the pointer back in the caller, all reallocation changes are lost. Either become a *3-star programmer* (not a compliment) or return and assign the new pointer address.

Comment: Second point -- you need to *Validate* every *User-Input* and every *Allocation* to ensure they succeed to have any confidence in the operation of your code. [10 Commandments for C Programmers - No. 6](http://www.seebs.net/c/10com.html) *Ye be warned...*

Answer (score 2):

Your `add_row` function modifies `matrix` and renders the old value invalid but doesn't return the new value to the caller.

Comment: It does not have to return, I try to change data by memory modifications by pointers.

Comment: That would be a way to return the new value, but alas you don't do that. You actually pass `matrix` to the function, not a pointer to it. So when you change its value, the new value does not get communicated back to the caller. (How does the caller know what value `realloc` returned?)

Comment: To be honest, I didn't know, that realloc change memory locations, so I thoungh that pointer is not changing.

Comment: Then why did you do `matrix = realloc(...`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `add_row()` changes the value of `matrix` via `realloc()`, but the calling function - in `main()`, maybe? doesn't see that change.

In the same way, if `add_row()` changed the value of `cols_amount`, that change would not be visible to the caller. You don't care about that.

But you DO care about the *row* count change being visible to the caller, so you correctly pass the *address* of `rows_amount` so that when `add_row()` adds one to the row count, the caller sees that change.

Do the same thing with `matrix` by passing the address of the pointer:

```
int add_row(int ***pMatrix, int *rows_amount, int cols_amount)
{
    (*pMatrix) = realloc(*pMatrix, ...)
    (*pMatrix)[*rows_amount - 1] = ...

    // use (*pMatrix) where you used to use matrix
}

int main()
{
   ...
   add_row(&matrix, &rows, cols);
```

**EDIT**: to answer something from the comments;

When you allocate memory, that space is reserved for you and you get a pointer back, and the *next* memory request is often allocated right after the first one, perhaps separated by a bit of padding or housekeeping.  This means that the first and second allocations are more or less right next to each other.

```
|---alloc1---|

|---alloc1---| |---alloc2---|
```

The only way `realloc(alloc1)` can return the same pointer is if there's free space *after* the allocation: if this happens, then it will adjust housekeeping and return the same pointer.

But here we find that `alloc2` is in the way, there's no room to extend `alloc1`, so it has no choice but to reserve a new spot, copy stuff over, and release the first one:

```
|---alloc1---|

|---alloc1---| |---alloc2---|
               |---alloc2---| |---bigger alloc1-------|
```

I would imagine that asking `realloc()` for *less* memory would return the same pointer because it can just update the housekeeping, but it's not required to do so, and in practice you never ever ever rely on it.

**EDIT2** In practice, I would not solve the problem this way. I'd create a structure that holds the pointer plus the row/column counts, so it could be passed around as a single item rather than all the three parts at a time.

```
struct matrix {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int **cells;
};
```